# How to Structure Three-Dimensional Lag TimeSteps for an LSTM in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, reshape

I understand LSTMS require a three-dimensional dataset to function following this format, N_samples x TimeSteps x Variables. I want to restructure my data from a single timestep for all of my rows into Lag timesteps by hours. The idea is that the LSTM would then batch train from hour to hour (from 310033 rows x 1 Timestep x 83 Variables to 310033 rows x 60 Timestep x 83 Variables).

However, the losses of my model were weird (increasing training loss with epochs) and training accuracy decreased from the single time step to the lagged time steps. This makes me believe I did this transformation wrong. Is this the correct way to restructure the data or is there a better way to do so?

The data is time series data in 1 sec recordings and has already been preprocessed to be within a range of 0-1, One-Hot encoded, cleaned, etc...

Current Transformation in Python:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled, target, train_size=.7, shuffle = False) 
#reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
#X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])) - Old method for 1 timestep
#X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])) - Old method for 1 timestep

#Generate Lag time Steps 3D framework for LSTM
#As required for LSTM networks, we must reshape the input data into N_samples x TimeSteps x Variables
hours = len(X_train)/3600
hours = math.floor(hours) #Most 60 min hours availible in subset of data 
temp =[]
# Pull hours into the three dimensional feild
for hr in range(hours, len(X_train) + hours):
    temp.append(scaled[hr - hours:hr, 0:scaled.shape[1]])
X_train = np.array(temp) #Export Train Features

hours = len(X_test)/3600
hours = math.floor(hours) #Most 60 min hours availible in subset of data 
temp =[]
# Pull hours into the three dimensional feild
for hr in range(hours, len(X_test) + hours):
    temp.append(scaled[hr - hours:hr, 0:scaled.shape[1]])
X_test = np.array(temp) #Export Test Features
```

Data Shape after Transformation:

[image: Shape of X_train after Lag Timesteps]

Model Injection:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, 
                   input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.15)) #15% drop out layer
#model.add(BatchNormalization())

#Layer 2
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.15)) #15% drop out layer

#Layer 3 - return a single vector
model.add(Dense(32))
#Output of 2 because we have 2 classes
model.add(Dense(2, activation= 'sigmoid'))
# Define optimiser
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, decay=1e-6)
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', # Mean Square Error Loss = 'mse'; Mean Absolute Error = 'mae'; sparse_categorical_crossentropy
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Any input on how to improve performance or fix the Lag Timesteps?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to predict y against lagged and current values of x variables your y_train needs to start after 1st set of lagged values or y_train needs to be y_train[59:] and also your X_train needs to end withing training period and last observation of y_train should correspond to X_train which has latest data time point same as y_train. So take X_train[:y_train[59:].shape[0], 60, 83]

To elaborate a bit more, you need to fit:

X(t), X(t-1), X(t-2), ..., X(t-59) ---- > y(t)

X(t+1), X(t), X(t-1),..., X(t-58) ------> y(t+1)

The code you have written, if I am not wrong, is probably fitting the opposite:

X(t), X(t-1), X(t-2), ..., X(t-59) ---- > y(t-59)

Comment: thank you for your response! Could this be accomplished using **shift()** to the target field? Also, do you know how to deal with N_samples if I split the Lag Time Steps from one into 60 splits. Lets assume I use 60 Time Steps and my data 309600 rows in the initial data prior to the split. I could do a 70 - 30 split of training and testing (216720 and 92880 rows respectively) where each timestep is 3870 rows or about an hour of data. Would the structure be 3870 x 60 x 84 instead of 216720 x 60 x 84 for the testing data?

Comment: When you are taking 60 lag values your starting X_train for model fitting is (apart from lagged past values) X_train(60) and therefore just dropping y[:60] is enough. So, taking y_train[60:] should suffice. Also X_train should not go beyond y_train[60:].shape[0] and you need to take care of that also.

My idea is that: Firstly you do second to hour conversion, Secondly do the lagging and X to Y time mapping with required trimming, thirdly do the train test split. Your final training dimension would be (y_train[lag_hours:].shape[0], lag_hours, variable_numbers)